# check greater than or less than in wiremock

Tags: java, json, stubbing, wiremock

I have a situation where I need to check the amount and return the response accordingly.

If the amount is >=100, then response would be different, else for amount < 100, i need to send error response.

Please refer the sample json in request body.

> {
>      "accountName":"ABCZYZ",
>      "specialCode":"MYCODE",
>      "amount":"100",
>      "currencyType":"MYCURRENCY"
>   }

Below is my wiremock mapping file

> {
>    "request":
>      {
>        "urlPattern": "/some/url",
>        "method": "POST",
>        "bodyPatterns" : [ {
>           "matchesJsonPath" : "**$[?(@.amount < 100)]**"
>         } ]
>      },
>
> "response":
>      {
>        "status": 200,
>        "body": "MY_REPONSE_IN_JSON_FORMAT"
>      }
>   }

I am facing issue reagrding the above matching pattern.

Could anyone please help me for the same?

Thanks
M

Answer (score 2):

Try changing "100" to 100

tested like below :

Request :

```
{
    "accountName": "ABCZYZ",
    "specialCode": "MYCODE",
    "amount": 100,
    "currencyType": "MYCURRENCY"
}
```

JsonPath:

```
$[?(@.amount <= 100)]
```

Response:

```
[{"accountName":"ABCZYZ","specialCode":"MYCODE","amount":100,"currencyType":"MYCURRENCY"}]
```

Comment: I cannot change the request, this is what the 3rd party API needs. Even though I tried doing the same, I'm not getting the desired result. Thanks for your help.

Comment: could you please some part of the code. so that I can see what you are trying and replicate the same.

Comment: I'm testing this mock by Postman, so no code is involved here.

1. Initializing wiremock standalone jar.
2. Hitting the POST url via Postman.